# Reference counting при использовании replaceObjectAtIndex NSMutableArray

Tags: foundation, objective-c, xcode

```
    NSString *str=@"string 1";
    NSMutableString *str2=[NSMutableString stringWithString:str];
    NSLog(@"%lx str2 retainCount after creating", (unsigned long)[str2 retainCount]);

    NSMutableArray *arr=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:str,str2,nil];
    NSLog(@"%lx str2 retainCount after adding to array", (unsigned long)[str2 retainCount]);
    [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:str];
    NSLog(@"%lx str2 retainCount after replacing", (unsigned long)[str2 retainCount]);
```

После того, как я заменяю 0 элемент (arr) на str2, retainCount str2 не увеличивается почему-то. Если str2 до этого не было в arr, то retainCount увеличивается на 1. Вопрос: почему так? По идее, в первом элементы мы добавили еще одну ссылку на str2.

Вывод вышеописанного кода:

```
 1 str2 retainCount after creating
 2 str2 retainCount after adding to array
 2 str2 retainCount after replacing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы заменяете нулевой элемент массива на `str`, а не на `str2`.
Поменяйте `str` на `str2` в `[arr replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:str];` и `[str2 retainCount]` увеличится на 1.